# I'm unable to set a main template, only works on my custom module

Tags: magento

I think my theme is a fairly basic one, which I have located at design>frontend>mytheme

I then I have my "package" as "mytheme" in the config>design settings.

The issue I'm having is that I want a main template file for everything, but it only is working on my custom module pages, and not the default magento pages like the login/registration pages, or the home page.

The following is a basic local.xml file for my theme. The js files are being added on all pages, it's just that it isn't using my default template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default translate="label" module="page">
        <label>All Pages</label>
        <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="single_column.phtml">

        <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>lib/jquery/noconflict.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/builder.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/effects.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/dragdrop.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/controls.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/slider.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/form.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>mage/cookies.js</script></action>

            <block type="page/js_cookie" name="js_cookies" template="page/js/cookie.phtml"/>
        </block>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
                <label>Main Content Area</label>
            </block>



        </block>

        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>css/local.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
        </reference>
     </default>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create one block in header and add all your js file.
Or if you want to call js from xml file then you need to add in your local.xml reference in which page you want to add js look following code :

```
<catalog_product_view>

     <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
             </reference>
     <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>firstyourscript.js</script></action>
           <action method="addJs"><script>secondyourscript.js</script></action>
        </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

In this way you can add your js files in all pages.You need to set template with reference name root for all page you need to add in your local.xml

Comment: Sorry, my question isn't really about the js. The js is being added to all my pages correctly. My issue is regarding the fact that the single_column template is not being used on my homepage, login/registration pages, only my custom module pages. I don't know why it's happening.

Comment: answer edited you need to add all handle in your local.xml and within it you need to add reference root.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. How does this all handle become the default one? What is 'catalog_product_view'? Is it arbitrary or must I set it as the 'default' somewhere? thanks

Comment: Checking the base and rwd themes, the same thing happens. It appears it uses different templates for different page even though they have the default template set as "3columns.phtml". If there is a way to get a template file across the board....

Comment: in catalog.xml you will find 'catalog_product_view' this is handle when product detail page you see in site. my above code is set root template for product detail page. you also will find handle 'catalog_category_default' for category page.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that in the administration settings for the default home page it had the 2column template set, which overrides whatever you have set as the default.

To get around it, I just created my own module/controller and set that as the default home page.